# Cannot Install laravel/ui in Laravel 6.x

Tags: php, laravel

I've set up a new Laravel 6 project and am trying to install some packages. So far, I have downloaded the core packages, now I'm trying to make Auth, but when I'm trying to install laravel/ui, the composer gives error message like this

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
- laravel/ui 2.x-dev requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4].
- laravel/ui v2.0.0 requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4].
- laravel/ui v2.0.1 requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4].
- don't install illuminate/filesystem 7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
- don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
- don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
- don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
- don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
- don't install illuminate/filesystem v7.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.0, required as ^6.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.0].
- Installation request for laravel/ui ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[2.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.1].
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your error indicating

> `laravel/ui 2.x-dev` requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> satisfiable
>   by illuminate/filesystem[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3,
>   v7.0.4].

You are installing `Laravel ui 2.x` that depends on `Laravel` 7 that is why you are getting this error.

To solve this you need to upgrade your project to `Laravel 7` or need to install `Laravel ui 1.x`